# error: 'spdiag' undefined near line

Tags: octave, sparse-matrix

I am introducing into Octave programming and I am interested in defining an sparse matrix as  [here](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/octave3/octave_205.html), so I have the following code:

```
  spdiag ([1, 2, 3], 1)
```

And I got the error "error: 'spdiag' undefined near line 1 column 1"

I understand that for some reason the Octave build-in function *spdiag* cannot be found but I do not understand whether I have to include some Octave module and/or set some environmental variable in order to make it work.

I would really appreciate some help.

By the way I am working under Ubuntu 13.10 and the octave version is 3.6.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The manual you are reading for a very very old version of Octave. If you go to the [main page](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/octave3/index.html), you'll notice this is the manual for version 3.0.2 and released in August 2008. The function `spdiag` was deprecated in version 3.2.0 and removed in 3.6.0.

If you use the Octave website, you will always get the [latest version](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/) of the manual. In addition, the manual in both html and pdf forms is part of the Octave installation. Since you are using Ubuntu, you can install the package `octave-doc` to get the manual for the same version you have installed.